# D3.js v4: Text appended to partition layout but not showing up

Tags: d3.js

Text is appended and shows correctly in the console but doesn't display on the graph... It also contains the correct data for each rect/partition/shape. Graph continues to look exactly like [this.](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/c4eb1f1a888c94bcd3f57df805a34cc4) My data object is reading a file with the exact same data as shown in the code on that link.

This is what shows in the console:

```
<rect x="300" y="66.66666666666667" width="100" height="66.66666666666667"><text x="0" y="0" font-size="12px" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="calibri">B2</text></rect>
    <text x="0" y="0" font-size="12px" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" font-family="calibri">B2</text>
</rect>
```

When I hover over these items in the console, it lays a blue projection over the rect to show which element it is on the page, but doesn't do this for the text element.

Here is the working code: (copied from above link for learning)

```
<style>
rect {
  fill: #333;
  opacity: 0.3;
  stroke: white;
}
</style>

<center>   
<svg height="900" width="900">
<g></g>    
</svg>
</center>

<script>
var dataGlob;

d3.json("circPack.json", function(error, data) {
    if (error)
      throw error;
    dataGlob = data;

    var partitionLayout = d3.partition()
  .size([400, 200]);

var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

rootNode.sum(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

partitionLayout(rootNode);

var nodes = d3.select("svg g")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0; })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })

nodes
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "calibri")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.children === undefined ? d.data.name : '';
  })

});

</script>
```

Everything was going great until I started working with D3's layouts/hierarchy.

Comment: Apologies, I have already fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at examples of other types of layouts and noticed they had appended "g" elements and THEN proceeded to appended their other shapes. Fixing the code a bit to append "g" and then the rects has allowed some text to become visible.

This is the only part of the code I had to update:

```
var nodes = d3.select("svg g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(rootNode.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append("g");

nodes
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y0; })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return d.x1 - d.x0; })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
```